# Native Boot differencing VHD with parent from different volume

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, ssd, virtualization

Is there a way how to boot Windows 7 from a differencing VHD which is located on different drive than its parent VHD?

Here is appropriate part of output of bcdedit command:

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  vhd=[D:]\OS\Win7_differencing.vhd
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {bee8d180-9034-11e3-998e-08002793cbd4}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                vhd=[D:]\OS\Win7_differencing.vhd
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {bee8d17e-9034-11e3-998e-08002793cbd4}
nx                      OptIn
```

This works perfectly when I have `[D:]\OS\Win7_differencing.vhd` on the same volume as its parent, but I would like to have the parent VHD on SSD drive and the differencing VHD on HDD drive.

One of the reasons I want this setup is the impossibility of securely wiping files from SSD.
I wan't my system to be fast and located on SSH but I want the changes which I could eventually want to wipe to be located on HDD.

If I try to move or create the differencing VHD on different drive (using diskpart) windows fail to boot.

Comment: I wonder if creating a junction would help, pointing from the original location to the new location on the HDD?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem myself. Very annoying, and I couldn't find any way to workaround it.

There doesn't seem to be much official documentation confirming the restriction. The best I could find was [this paragraph in a TechNet FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440865.aspx):

> **You must keep both files (the parent VHD and the differencing VHD) in the same directory on a local volume for native-boot scenarios.**
>   For native-boot VHDs, the parent VHD and the differencing disk cannot
>   reside on different volumes, even if they reside on the same local
>   disk. However, when you attach a differencing VHD that is not used for
>   native boot (for example, if you plan to use it for image management),
>   the parent VHD can be in different directories, and on a different
>   volume or even on a remote share.